# Tor on a USB drive on different operating systems

Tags: linux, mac, tor-install

According to the [documentation](https://www.torproject.org/projects/torbrowser.html.en#windows):

> If you want to move it to a different computer or limit the traces you leave behind, save it to a USB disk.

But this is only mentioned for Windows instructions. I wonder if I can take similar steps on macOS and Linux, i.e. choose the USB drive as the destination folder during the installation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can.

**Linux:**
Extract the Tor Browser Tar to the USB drive and use it from there.

**Mac OS X:**
Same as Linux just with `dmg` file.